# Run a job based on value of previous job in Python Schedule

Tags: python, jobs, schedule

Hey guys I am trying to make an alarm that adjusts it's time based on commute time.
My code checks for commute time one hour before the Alarm time and then readjusts the alarm by commute time.
The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to return the updated value of alarmTime which will be used to schedule another job based on updated alarmTime from Job1

I have tried to make alarmTime global so I don't have to return the value but it doesn't help.
What should I do?
Thanks in Advance.

```
def job1(alarmTime,approxTime):
    updatedTime=getApproxT1() #check for update one hour before alarm 
    
    xmins=timediff(approxTime,updatedTime) #a function that finds out time diff
    
    if xmins > 0:
        alarmTime = alarmTime-timedelta(minutes=-xmins)
    elif xmins < 0:
        alarmTime = alarmTime+timedelta(minutes=-xmins) 
    else:
        print("no change")
    print(alarmTime)


schedule.every().day.at("08:00").do(job1,alarmTime,approxtime)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Use a class? You can also tag jobs which can be cancelled. You could then add a new job at a different time.

Comment: yes but how do I get the return value from the first job? My second job will be triggered on the time value that I get from first job.

Comment: You would not need to get the return value. You can re-schedule the function in the function

Comment: Late reply, nevertheless try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64263432/change-the-scheduling-time-python/64265384#64265384. I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a [listener](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/listeners.html), or, if you're expecting things to get very complicated, some kind of Publish/Subscribe (pubsub) library.

Rather than return a message, have your second task subscribe or listen to an action/publish event that your first alarm will broadcast to let dependent alarms know it is time to proceed.