# Updating the input variables for a function which runs with schedule.run_pending

Tags: python, variables, schedule, auto-update

I am working with the module "schedule" and trying to figure out how to update the input variables for the function "automated_ticket_booking" while it is running continuously due to schedule.run_pending().

The initial values are given by the function get_events which runs once at the start of the script. My goal ist to update the variables in the "automated_ticket_booking" function and use the returned values as new input data.

I hope the example code will help you to understand my problem.
I appreciate any help on this task.

Thank You!

```
import schedule

def get_events():
    event_date = "01.01.1918"
    event_timeslots = "08.15 - 10.00"
    return event_date, event_timeslots

def automated_ticket_booking(event_date, event_timeslots):
    print(event_date + " : " + event_timeslots)
    event_date = "15.06.2022"
    event_timeslots = "23:15 - 23:48"
    return event_date, event_timeslots

# -------------
[event_date, event_timeslots] = get_events()

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(automated_ticket_booking,
                          event_date,
                          event_timeslots)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

Comment: Why not use the `schedule` module to run a different function which first calls `get_events()` and then supplies the results to a call to `automated_ticket_booking()`?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I am not totally sure - it think it wont work! Could you explain it to me with the example?

Comment: This topic refers to a kind of similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64263432/change-the-scheduling-time-python

Answer (score 0):

Lets make another function which does two jobs:

```py
def booking_from_latest_events():
    event_date, event_timeslots = get_events()
    automated_ticket_booking(event_date, event_timeslots)

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(booking_from_latest_events)
```